# Math formula for changing number between two range

Tags: swift, math, formula

Here is my issue as an example:
I have two variables, minNumber = 12 & maxNumber = 24 and a maxLimit = 30
and I have a percentage between 1.0 - 0.0, I want the following result:
when the percentage decrease from 1.0 to 0.5, I want minNumber to increase to the maxLimit, and when the percentage decrease from 0.5 to 0.0, the maxLimit went down to maxNumber
so,

```
percentage = 1.0
var result = 0
while percentage >= 0 {
    if percentage < 0.5 {
        result = 12.1, 12.2, ..., 29.8, 29.9, 30 (what formula can produce this sequence)
    } else {
        result = 30, 29.9, ..., 24.1, 24.0 (what formula can produce this sequence)
    }
    percentage = percentage - 0.1
    print("\(result)")
}
```

Comment: Try to explain better what you are trying to achieve. I read a couple of times your question but can't really figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want `result` value to "move" in an angle-like shape from `minNumber` via `maxLimit` to `maxNumber`. The basis behind this transformation is following formula. If you have a value `X` from a range `Xmin` to `XMax` and you want to map it to a range `Ymin` to `Ymax` then

```
 Y = (Ymin * (Xmax - X) + Ymax * (X - Xmin)) / (Xmax - Xmin)
```

For you case you should apply this formula for two intervals:

1. mapping `[0; 0.5]` range to `[minNumber; maxLimit]`
2. mapping `[0.5; 1.0]` range to `[maxLimit; maxNumber]`

I think the code becomes more clear if you call:

- `leftNumber` = `minNumber`
- `middleNumber` = `maxLimit`
- `rightNumber` = `maxNumber`

and use two `while` loops instead of one with inner `if`:

```
let leftNumber = 12.0       // minNumber 
let middleNumber = 30.0     // maxLimit 
let rightNumber = 23.0      // maxNumber 
let leftPercentage = 0.0
let middlePercentage = 0.5
let rightPercentage = 1.0
let percentageStep = 0.1

var percentage = leftPercentage
var result = 0.0
while percentage <= middlePercentage {
    result = ((percentage - leftPercentage) * middleNumber + (middlePercentage - percentage) * leftNumber)/(middlePercentage - leftPercentage)
    percentage = percentage + percentageStep
    print("\(result)")
}
while percentage <= rightPercentage {
    result = ((rightPercentage - percentage) * middleNumber + (percentage - middlePercentage) * rightNumber)/(rightPercentage - middlePercentage)
    percentage = percentage + percentageStep
    print("\(result)")
}
```

You can see output of this code [here](https://iswift.org/playground?wQRRpW&v=3)

---

**Update: Where the formula comes from?**

When we say that "you have a value `X` from a range `Xmin` to `XMax` and you want to map it to a range `Ymin` to `Ymax`", what exactly do you mean by "map"? Usually what you want is that `X` splits the `[Xmin, Xmax]` range in the same proportion as `Y` splits the `[Ymin, Ymax]` range. Let's write that:

```
(X - Xmin)/(Xmax - Xmin) = (Y - Ymin)/(Ymax - Ymin)
```

If you try to solve it for `Y` you can see that:

```
(Y - Ymin) = (X - Xmin)/(Xmax - Xmin)*(Ymax - Ymin) =
= (Ymax * (X - Xmin) - Ymin * (X-Xmin))/(Xmax - Xmin)
```

so

```
Y  = (Ymax * (X - Xmin) - Ymin * (X - Xmin))/(Xmax - Xmin) + Ymin =
= (Ymax * (X - Xmin) + Ymin * (Xmin - X) + Ymin * (Xmax - Xmin))/(Xmax - Xmin) =
= (Ymax * (X - Xmin) + Ymin * (Xmax - X))/(Xmax - Xmin)
```

which is exactly that formula.

Comment: Thank you, that what I'm looking for, can you please briefly clarify the math behind it so I can understand from where this formula come from `y = (Ymin * (Xmax - X) + Ymax * (X - Xmin)) / (Xmax - Xmin)`

Comment: @Scar, it comes from basic algebra. Take a look at my explanation at the end of the answer.